# How to format json response in this rails custom controller action and how ajax will be used?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm new to frontend and rails.. I'm confused about a controller action I'm writing. Basically, this action serves as an endpoint that will be called through an ajax polling. On a webpage, the button will have a `remote: true` and call $ajax in the respective js file for controller.

The controller action just provides 2 numbers when it's called. The frontend will divide the 2 and calculate a completion percentage or heck I can provide the division. I've gotten this far. How can I write ajax poll for this in jquery or coffee? Am I formatting the json response correctly? How will ajax parse it?

```
class FileProcessorController < ApplicationController


    #  Below Contains the button. Coffeescript file will be associated for this page
    #  jquery/coffeescript will contain an ajax poll on get_progress action
    def upload
            #  Renders upload.html.erb by default which contains the button
    end

    # This endpoint will be called by AJAX poll in the controller's cofeescript file.
    def get_progress
        redis_key = session[:redis_key]
        total_records = session[:file_records]

        done_cnt = $redis.get(redis_key)
        resp = {total_amount: total_records amount_done: done_cnt}

        respond_to |format| do
            format.json {resp.to_json}
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try snippet from [THIS](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/jquery/ajax) site:

```
$.ajax '/',
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'html'
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        $('body').append "AJAX Error: #{textStatus}"
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        $('body').append "Successful AJAX call: #{data}"
```

Then you can handle adding/changing values in success callback. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: default name for first param.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that I use.

`target` = the url that you're hitting on your server - including any parameters.

The response is returned to the `data` object that you'll need to parse into JSON so that you can then get direct access to the items within the response.

The example below might return JSON like `{"status":true,"message":"Something happened"}`.  After parsing I can then get to `json_response.message = "Something happened"`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: target,
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );}
  })
.done(function( data ) {
  json_response = JSON.parse(data);
  alert(json_response.message);
})
```